# Where can I find statistics of polio cases in different countries

Tags: data-request, medical

I would like to know how many cases of polio were reported in different countries for last 20 years or more. So far I've looked into the [WHO webiste](http://www.who.int/mediacentre/factsheets/fs114/en/) and also [The Global Polio Eradication Initiative](http://www.polioeradication.org/dataandmonitoring/poliothisweek.aspx), but haven't find what I am looking for.

I also wanted to add the 'polio' and 'vaccination' tags to this question, but I don't have enough rep. Would be grateful if someone with enough rep can add these tags. Thank you.

Comment: I added some tags, but 'polio' and 'vaccination' don't exist. Tags with only one question aren't so helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a tough one to find. The WHO, CDC, and GPEI were referenced all over the web as sources, but I couldn't find any pre-compiled data tables. WHO had a data system that includes polio cases but it only went back to 2010.

Then - I found a citation in a PDF of WHO's Global Health Observatory reports. The report has the most recent data, but also a link back to a data series called the vaccines preventable diseases monitoring system. A search through that database, with some filtering, finally leads you to this:

http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/timeseries/tsincidencepolio.html

It's country data from 1980 to 2014, reported cases of polio.
This also contains data on several other diseases: Diphtheria, Japanese encephalitis, Measles, Mumps, Pertussis, Rubella, Rubella (CRS), Tetanus, and   Yellow fever.

Comment: Thank you for finding and sharing such a wealth of information. This has yearly data on several diseases including polio. Great find!